# Best practices for internal api calls to external apis with buffer

Tags: python-3.x

I have different external APIs doing basically the same things but in a different way : add product informations (ext_api).

I would like to make an adapter API that would call, behind the scene, the different external APIs (adapter_api).

My problem is the following : the external APIs are optimised when calling them with a batch of products attributes. However, my API would be optimised on a product by product basis.

I would like to somehow make a buffer of product attributes that would grow when I call my adapter_api. When the number of product attributes reach a certain limit, the ext_api would be called and the buffer would be reset and ready to receive more product attributes.

I'm wondering how to achieve that. I was thinking of making a REST api in python that would store the buffer of product attributes. I would like this REST api to be able to scale on a Kubernetes cluster : it would need low latency, and several instance of this API would write in the buffer of products until one of them reach the limit and make the call to the external API.

Here is what I have in mind :
[image]

Are there any best practices concerning the buffer on this use case ? To add some extra informations : my main purpose here is to hide from internal business APIs (not drawn) the complexity of calling many different external APIs each of which have their own rules and credentials.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us your performance evaluation criteria.
You *did* tell us this:

> don't know how to store the buffer : I would like to avoid databases or files.

which makes little sense,
since there's a simple answer to this question:

> Is there any best practices on this use case ?

Yes. The best practice is to append requests to `buffer.txt`
and send the batch when that file exceeds some threshold.

A convenient way to implement the threshold would be
to send when [`getsize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) reports a large enough value.
If requests are of quite different size and the batch
size really matters to you, then append a single byte
to a 2nd file, and use size of that to indicate how
many entries are enqueued.

## requirements

The heart of your question seems to revolve around
what was left unsaid:

1. What is the cost function for sending too many "small" batches to ext_api?
2. What is the cost function for the consumer of the adapter_api, what does it care about? Low latency return, perhaps?
3. If ext_api permanently fails (say, a day of downtime), do we have some responsibility for quickly notifying the consumer that its updates are going into a black hole?

And why would using the filesystem be inappropriate?
It seems a perfect match for your needs.

Consider using a global in-memory object,
such as list or queue for the batch you're accumulating.
You might want to protect accesses with a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#rlock-objects).

Maybe your client doesn't really want a
one-product-at-a-time API.
Maybe you'd prefer to have your client
accumulate items,
sending only when its batch size is big enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! You're right, I will rephrase my question.